# Numpy array from file with read() (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

For a text file (`testfile.txt`):

```
# blah blah blah

Unpleasant astonished an diminution up. Noisy an their of meant. Death means up civil do an offer wound of. 
//Called square an in afraid direct. 


{Resolution} diminution conviction so (mr at) unpleasing simplicity no. 
/*No it as breakfast up conveying earnestly
```

When storing the content of a text file inside a **numpy array**, I am having trouble understanding the difference between:

A. when the text file is opened directly (with no `read()`) and stored in the numpy array, and

B. when the text file is first opened with a `read()` and then stored in the numpy array.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy    

# open directly with no read
a = numpy.array([str(i) for i in open(r'C:\testfile.txt', 'r')])

# open with read then store in numpy *how I want to do it*
f = open(r'C:\testfile.txt', 'r').read()
b = numpy.array([str(i) for i in f])

print("A")
print(a)
print()
print("B")
print(b)
```

My question is **how to change the `numpy.array([str(i) for i in f])` command so that the resulting numpy array hold the contents of the text file in the way that *output A* does** (seen below).

Output:

```
A
['# blah blah blah\n' '\n'
 'Unpleasant astonished an diminution up. Noisy an their of meant. Death means up civil do an offer wound of. \n'
 '//Called square an in afraid direct. \n' '\n' '\n'
 '{Resolution} diminution conviction so (mr at) unpleasing simplicity no. \n'
 '/*No it as breakfast up conveying earnestly ']

B
['#' ' ' 'b' 'l' 'a' 'h' ' ' 'b' 'l' 'a' 'h' ' ' 'b' 'l' 'a' 'h' '\n' '\n'
 'U' 'n' 'p' 'l' 'e' 'a' 's' 'a' 'n' 't' ' ' 'a' 's' 't' 'o' 'n' 'i' 's'
 'h' 'e' 'd' ' ' 'a' 'n' ' ' 'd' 'i' 'm' 'i' 'n' 'u' 't' 'i' 'o' 'n' ' '
 'u' 'p' '.' ' ' 'N' 'o' 'i' 's' 'y' ' ' 'a' 'n' ' ' 't' 'h' 'e' 'i' 'r'
 ' ' 'o' 'f' ' ' 'm' 'e' 'a' 'n' 't' '.' ' ' 'D' 'e' 'a' 't' 'h' ' ' 'm'
 'e' 'a' 'n' 's' ' ' 'u' 'p' ' ' 'c' 'i' 'v' 'i' 'l' ' ' 'd' 'o' ' ' 'a'
 'n' ' ' 'o' 'f' 'f' 'e' 'r' ' ' 'w' 'o' 'u' 'n' 'd' ' ' 'o' 'f' '.' ' '
 '\n' '/' '/' 'C' 'a' 'l' 'l' 'e' 'd' ' ' 's' 'q' 'u' 'a' 'r' 'e' ' ' 'a'
 'n' ' ' 'i' 'n' ' ' 'a' 'f' 'r' 'a' 'i' 'd' ' ' 'd' 'i' 'r' 'e' 'c' 't'
 '.' ' ' '\n' '\n' '\n' '{' 'R' 'e' 's' 'o' 'l' 'u' 't' 'i' 'o' 'n' '}' ' '
 'd' 'i' 'm' 'i' 'n' 'u' 't' 'i' 'o' 'n' ' ' 'c' 'o' 'n' 'v' 'i' 'c' 't'
 'i' 'o' 'n' ' ' 's' 'o' ' ' '(' 'm' 'r' ' ' 'a' 't' ')' ' ' 'u' 'n' 'p'
 'l' 'e' 'a' 's' 'i' 'n' 'g' ' ' 's' 'i' 'm' 'p' 'l' 'i' 'c' 'i' 't' 'y'
 ' ' 'n' 'o' '.' ' ' '\n' '/' '*' 'N' 'o' ' ' 'i' 't' ' ' 'a' 's' ' ' 'b'
 'r' 'e' 'a' 'k' 'f' 'a' 's' 't' ' ' 'u' 'p' ' ' 'c' 'o' 'n' 'v' 'e' 'y'
 'i' 'n' 'g' ' ' 'e' 'a' 'r' 'n' 'e' 's' 't' 'l' 'y' ' ']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply split the output of `read()` into separate lines:

```
def load_entire_file_into_memory_and_then_convert(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as input_file:
     full_file_contents = input_file.read()
     lines_of_file = full_file_contents.split('\n')
     return numpy.array(lines_of_file)
```

And your other version:

```
def load_file_line_by_line(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as input_file:
     lines_of_file = [line for line in input_file]
     return numpy.array(lines_of_file)
```

Note the semantic difference between these two versions and why you were getting different results; when you do "for ... in" on a file, the results that you get back are individual lines. If you call `read()`, then you get the entire file as a single string (with lines separated by newlines), and "for ... in" on a string gives you the individual characters of the string (not lines). Although there may be cases where using `read()` is more convenient (e.g. when you really want to load all lines at once), it is usually more scalable / better habit to process files line-by-line (using your first approach), as this allows you do reduce your memory footprint (such as in other applications that do not require all lines to be in memory all at once and can operate on just a single line of the file at a time).

Comment: For text files `readlines()` is usually more useful than `read()`.  The result is similar to iterating on the open file.

Comment: Agreed. readlines() is basically the same as doing "for ... in" on the file object. The question, though, is directly asking how to do it with "read()".